# Get control from style within style

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a style :

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxStyle">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid>
                     <Button x:Name="Button1" />
                </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate/>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter> 
</Style>

<Style TargetType="local:MyControl">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyControl">
                <Grid>
                     ...
                     <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Style="{StaticRessource TextBoxStyle}/>
                     ...
                </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate/>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter> 
</Style>
```

the problem is that I can't get the "Button1", code behind :

```
public class MyControl : ItemsSource
{

    private TextBox _textBox1;
    private Button _button1;

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        _textBox1 = (TextBox)GetTemplateChild("TextBox1");

        base.OnApplyTemplate();

    }

}
```

In wpf i can do :

```
_button1 = (Button)_textBox1.Template.FindName("Button1");
```

But the "FindName()" method does't exist in uwp, so how can i get the Button1 ?

Thank's !

EDIT :

If we look at [AutoSuggestBox's style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185404.aspx) we have the style AutoSuggestBox and the AutoSuggestBoxTextBoxStyle. The autosuggestbox raise the event "QuerySubmitted" which is from the button "QueryButton", which is in the AutoSuggestBoxTextBoxStyle. So he can have access to the button right ?

Comment: In code behind you are creating an instance in the same class. Whereas in style both the styles are independent of each other. Be more specific if this does not shed any light on your question. Be more specific in what are you expecting in the style? Which style you want to get the values ?

Comment: I want to do the same as AutoSuggestBox witch is raise the event of the button clicked in AutoSuggestBox class, i have edtied my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, you created a Templated Control. [GetTemplateChild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.gettemplatechild.aspx) method is used for get the child element from the template. The above code snap is inside `MyControl` class and we can get child element from the `MyControl` template as you did to find the `TextBox1` . But for `Button1`, it is not inside the template of `MyControl`(it is in template of `_textbox1`), it seems like we cannot get it.

> so how can i get the Button1 ?

We can get the `Button1` after `MyControl` rendered by [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br243038). Here is a demo about creating a `MyControl` in `MainPage` and then get the `Button1` element by VisualTreeHelper.

Xaml Code

```
<local:MyControl x:Name="mycontrol" Height="200" Width="200"></local:MyControl>   
<Button x:Name="getbutton1" Click='getbutton1_Click' Content="Get button1"></Button>
```

Code behind

```
  private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
  {
      if (depObj != null)
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
          {
              DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
              if (child != null && child is T)
              {
                  yield return (T)child;
              }

              foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
              {
                  yield return childOfChild;
              }
          }
      }
  }

  private void getbutton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      Button _button1 = null;
      IEnumerable<Button> buttons = FindVisualChildren<Button>(mycontrol);
      foreach (var _button in buttons)
      {
          if (_button.Name == "Button1")
          {
             _button1 = _button;
          }
      }
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_button1.Content);
  }
```

> So he can have access to the button right ?

In that case, please check the `QueryButton` in the style, it is in a Grid, not a TextBox. And the 'textbox' you saw in the `AutoSuggestBox` is actually a ContentControl which is inside same Grid with `QueryButton`. So the button can be got.

Comment: I already knew this method but thx for the answer :), i have edited my post

Comment: @Caliphe, in that case, please check the `QueryButton` in the style, it is in a `Grid`, not a TextBox.  And the 'textbox' you saw in the `AutoSuggestBox` is actually a `ContentControl` which is inside same `Grid` with `QueryButton`. So the button can be got.

Comment: Ok thank's ! :D i didn't knew it was a ContentControl since it has the same name as the control

Comment: Done ! sorry i thought i did it